# Copy & Paste range as values into next empty column on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range (which varies based on inputs) as values into another sheet.
The code below seems to be copying on top of the last entry rather than into the next empty column.

```vb
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim emptyColumn As Long
        
    Set source = Sheets("Month Template")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")
        
    'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
    emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
    End If
    
    source.Range("m26:m35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: please could you clarify if you want to identify the first empty column (reading from the left) which may be sandwiched between other column content. Or, if you want to find the first empty column after the last column of content ignoring any blank columns that might be there?

Answer (score 1):

try with below

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim emptyColumn As Long
    Set source = Sheets("Month Template")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")
    'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
    emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    If emptyColumn > 1 Then
        emptyColumn = emptyColumn + 1
    End If
    source.Range("m26:m35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)
End Sub
```

Comment: If there's an empty column between various populated columns I don't believe that the suggested update will find the real 'last' column.

Comment: @robin, please go through the question. He is asking the next empty column

Comment: understand your point; my interpretation of the question is that the OP is looking for the rightmost empty column. This is based on their coding where he works leftward from the last column in the sheet. Understand your code picks up the first empty column looking rightward from column 1. I've asked the OP to elaborate.

Comment: @Robin the current code is something a co-worker gave me and not necessarily what I was after - I don't need the rightmost. Thank You for your assistance though :)

Comment: @NanAvanIllai I'm getting a Run Time 1004 error- "Application defined or object-defined error. Debug shows it on the line
   'source.Range("m26:m35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)'

Comment: @HayleyWatson, check your destination sheet name

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question that popped up.
When reading the Op's question, it looks like they want to make sure the 1st column is used and then move over to column 2.

```
If emptyColumn > 1 Then
```

When 1st using the copy&paste code `emptycolumn` will never be greater than 1.

A possible solution would be to 1st check if A1 ="" when emptycolumn=2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim source As Worksheet
    Dim destination As Worksheet
    Dim emptyColumn As Long

    Set source = Sheets("Month Template")
    Set destination = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'find empty Column (actually cell in Row 1)'
    emptyColumn = destination.Cells(1, destination.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    If destination.Cells(1, 1) = "" And emptyColumn = 2 Then emptyColumn = 1

    source.Range("m26:m35").Copy destination.Cells(1, emptyColumn)

End Sub
```